# Sending an image from Android to an ASP.NET Web Service to store in SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, android, sql, asp.net, bitmap

I'm trying to develop an app that can send an image along with some other info to an ASP.Net Web service and store it in SQL server as a field of image type. Here is what I've done:

I used the following method to Convert my bitmap to Base64 string, I got the bitmap from a .JPG file in my phone's SD card-

```
String BitmapToBase64StringConvertion(Bitmap myBitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    String someString = Base64.encodeToString(data, 0);

    return someString;
}
```

In the ASP.Net Web Service(C# behind) I've used the following method to get the image back-

```
private Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
                                         imageBytes.Length))
        {
            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Lastly, tried to insert the image using following code-

```
        Image convertedImage = Base64ToImage(image);

        string query = "INSERT INTO tblImageDetails (userId, doctorId, description, takenAt, capturedImage) 
                          VALUES ('" + userId + "', '" + doctorId + "', '" + description + "',  getDate() , " + convertedImage + ");";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbConnection);
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Finally I'm getting the following error in my LogCat:

> "ErrorMessage":"The multi-part identifier \"System.Drawing.Bitmap\" could not be bound.","Successful":false

I've tried in multiple ways, I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f768902-6199-4374-815d-dcf64381873f/insert-read-image-to-sql-2005-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral let's try this, use sql parameter instead

Comment: Thanks man, that was helpful! I just saved the base64 string in the database as varchar(max) instead of image and your trick worked! Now I could get the base64 and convert it back to image. Thanks again and wish I could up-vote or chose your comment as a solution! @ah_hau

Comment: post your code, then mark your code as answer to help other solve their problem as well. Glad to see it help.